# Simple Angular rails blog cant get post to show unless the page is reloaded

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, angularjs

Question is I have a super simple angular rails app. But for some reason my angular data(POST) doesn't show up in my table until I manually reload the page. Any help would greatly appreciated to help me solve this issue!

## Here is my angular stuff.

```
var post = angular.module('Post', ['ngResource']);

post.factory("Post", function($resource) {
 return $resource("post/:id", { id: '@id' }, {
    index:   { method: 'GET', isArray: true, responseType: 'json' },
    update:  { method: 'PUT', responseType: 'json' }
 });
})


post.controller("PostController", function($scope, $http, Post) {
  $scope.posts = Post.index()

  $scope.addPost = function() {
   post = Post.save($scope.newPost)

   $scope.posts.push(Post)
   $scope.newPost = {}
  }

  $scope.deletePost = function(index) {

    post = $scope.posts[index]
    Post.delete(post)
    $scope.posts.splice(index, 1);
 }
})
```

## Here is my Rails stuff

```
class PostController < ApplicationController


  before_action :authenticate_user!

  layout 'angular'

  respond_to :json

  def index
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render json: Post.all }
      format.html
    end
  end

  def create
    respond_with Post.create(post_params)
  end

  def destroy
    respond_with Post.destroy(params[:id])
  end

  private

  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:id, :created_at, :updated_at, :post_text, :user, :SUBJECT, :FIRST_NAME, :LAST_NAME, :EMAIL)
  end
 end
```

config/routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  devise_for :users, controllers: { sessions: 'sessions' }


  root to: 'post#index'

  #angular route
  resources :post, only: [:index, :create, :destroy], defaults: {format: :json}
  end 
end
```

## my view

```
%ul.nav.nav-pills.pull-left
  %li.active
    %a{:href => "home", :class => 'val_class'} Home

.container{"ng-app" => "Post"}
  %h1 Recent Post
  %div{"ng-controller" => "PostController"}
    .well
      %h3 Add a new post
      %form{"ng-submit" => "addPost()"}
        .row
          .col-xs-6
            %input.form-control{"ng-model" => "newPost.FIRST_NAME", :placeholder => "First Name", :type => "text"}/
          .col-xs-6
            %input.form-control{"ng-model" => "newPost.LAST_NAME", :placeholder => "Last Name", :type => "text"}/
        .row
          .col-xs-12
            %br/
            %input.form-control{"ng-model" => "newPost.SUBJECT", :placeholder => "Subject", :type => "text"}/
        .row
          .col-lg-12
            %br/
            %input.form-control{"ng-model" => "newPost.post_text", :placeholder => "Post Text", :type => "text"}/

        .row
          .col-xs-12.text-center
            %br/
            %input.btn.btn-primary{:type => "Submit", :value => "Add Post"}/

      %table.table.table-bordered.trace-table
        %thead
          %tr.trace-table
            %th.ts.jp{:style => 'border: solid black;'} First Name
            %th.ts.jp{:style => 'border: solid black;'} Last Name
            %th.ts.jp{:style => 'border: solid black;'} Post
            %th.ts.jp{:style => 'border: solid black;'} Subject
            %th.ts.jp{:style => 'border: solid black;'} Delete

        %tr.trace-table
          %tr{"ng-repeat" => "post in posts track by $index"}
            %td.trace-table{:style => 'border: solid black;'} {{ post.FIRST_NAME }}
            %td.trace-table{:style => 'border: solid black;'} {{ post.LAST_NAME }}
            %td.trace-table{:style => 'border: solid black;'} {{ post.post_text }}
            %td.trace-table{:style => 'border: solid black;'} {{ post.SUBJECT }}
            %td.trace-table{:style => 'border: solid black;'}
              %a.btn.btn-danger{"ng-click" => "deletePost($index)"} _
```

## Visual to show what I am talking about

## After I submit a post

[image: Before page reload after I submit a post]

## After manual page reload after I submit a post

[image: After page reload after I submit a post]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your addPost function as below:

```
$scope.addPost = function() {
   post = Post.save($scope.newPost)

   $scope.posts.push($scope.newPost)
   $scope.newPost = {}
}
```

Or you could use the return of `Post.save` which is more safe, because you might not be able to save your Post.

```
$scope.addPost = function() {
   post = Post.save($scope.newPost)
   post.$promise.then(function(res) {
      $scope.posts.push(res)
      $scope.newPost = {}
   }, function(res) {
     //Handle error
   })
}
```